# I cant seed my data into my database on my Laravel Project

Tags: php, laravel

So when i try to seed my database, i keep getting this error message in my terminal. It says my table doesnt exist but its named as menus. I searched in my project folder if mistakenly named anything but nothing showed up. I have tried renaming my files, models, factories, migration and seed files yet still the same result. It keeps saying my table doesnt exist even though my migration status is all good even.

This is the error message

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'restaurant_ordering_website.menus' doesn't exist (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `menus` (`item_name`, `price`, `description`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Magali Rosenbaum, 14.72, Pariatur natus officiis in impedit magni dolore neque fuga adipisci natus enim., 2023-02-24 04:15:08, 2023-02-24 04:15:08))
```

This is my migration status

```
Migration name .................................................................................................................... Batch / Status  
  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table ..................................................................................................... [1] Ran  
  2019_12_14_000001_create_personal_access_tokens_table .................................................................................... [1] Ran  
  2023_02_22_100010_menu_table ............................................................................................................. [1] Ran  
  2023_02_22_100024_orderitems_table ....................................................................................................... [1] Ran  
  2023_02_22_100035_order_table ............................................................................................................ [1] Ran
```

This is my databaseSeeder file

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

// use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;
use App\Models\Menu;
use App\Models\Order;
use App\Models\Orderitems;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use \App\Models\User;
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     */
    public function run(): void
    { 
        User::factory(10)->create();
        Menu::factory(10)->create();
        Orderitems::factory(10)->create();
        Order::factory(10)->create();

        // \App\Models\User::factory()->create([
        //     'name' => 'Test User',
        //     'email' => 'test@example.com',
        // ]);
    }
}
```

My menu factory

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

/**
 * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\Menu>
 */
class MenuFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            //
            'item_name'=>fake()->name(),
            'price'=>fake()->randomFloat(2, 5, 15),
            'description'=>fake()->sentence(10),
        ];
    }
}
```

This is Menu migration file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        //
        Schema::create('menu', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string("item_name");
            $table->float("price", 8, 2);
            $table->string("description");
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('menu');
    }
};
```

Comment: `menu` -> `menus` typo. Laravel always produce the table in plural form of the model if you created it using `php artisan  make:model Menu -m`

Comment: so do i need to change the name of the table or the name of the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may run the rollback command to delete the "menu" table from Database

> php artisan migrate:rollback
> --path="database/migrations/2023_02_22_100010_menu_table.php"

then edit the 2023_02_22_100010_menu_table.php file to change the table "name" menu to "menus"

```
Schema::create('menus', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string("item_name");
        $table->float("price", 8, 2);
        $table->string("description");
    });
```

also to down method

```
Schema::dropIfExists('menus');
```

run again migration command

```
php artisan migrate
```

Now you may seed

```
php artisan db:seed
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this managed to solve the problem.